# characterizations of a ω-cover in a Tychonoff space by co-zero sets

Tags: general-topology

My questions is: 1. How to characterize an $\omega$-cover in a Tychonoff space by co-zero sets. (An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\omega$-cover of $X$ if $X\not\in \mathcal{U}$ and for any finite subset $F$ of $X$ there is a $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $F\subseteq U$.)

Comment: How do you mean "characterise it". What kind of property are you looking for beyond the definition, which is clear enough?

Comment: In a Tychonoff space $X$ if each ω-cover contains a refinement consists of co-zero sets which is again a ω-cover?